# Filtering Out Data While Leaving NULL values

Tags: sql-server-2008, filter, null

I'm trying to figure out how to filter out certain data types while leaving the record displayed if the value happens to be NULL.

[image: Example]

This picture shows what I am hoping to accomplish. For Drive ID 652132, I would only like the record with EMET=3 filtering out the other equipment types/descriptions.  But if I put a EMET=3 in the Where clause, I lose the record with a Drive ID = 677266 because it has a NULL value in EMET.

Is there a way to sort this so that I keep records with EMET = 3 and NULL?

Thanks,

Comment: `WHERE EMET = 3 OR EMET IS NULL`

Comment: Wow, that easy!  If you change it to an answer, I will mark it correct.  Thanks!